# Undo "Flag as spam" on Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, spam

I've accidentally marked some reviews for some apps as spam, and they were removed (or were hidden from me).

The problem with clicking on this button is that there is no going back. It doesn't ask you anything about it.

How can I undo my mistakes?

Comment: I've done this myself. I don't think there is a way to undo it in the store. I can't find any of the reviews I've marked as 'helpful' or 'unhelpful' on my Google+ account or anywhere.

Comment: it was an accident. i was confused with the other buttons (maybe because I was tired, I don't remember). I don't want to harm others by this silly mistake. I don't even know what happens when I click on the "flag as spam" button, other than making it disappear for me.

Comment: It's probably the usual "investigate if x number of users report it as spam" system to be honest. And as you say it hides it from you. I doubt it will really effect anyone if just the one person does it. As I said I've done it by mistake myself a bunch of times. Edit: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/does-voting-on-market-comments-have-any-effect   Seems like what I said is about right, I think you're ok!

Comment: @RossC buy I was wrong and I wish to fix my mistakes... :(